# how to change the font color of confirmation box in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need to change the message style at Confirmation box as either the font color as red or font weight as bold.
please help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it.

But it might be useful to use jquery Library and jquery UI Dialog on your problem.

See this link: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Best Regards

Comment: Thank you.
How to check the jquery UI dialog is compatible with the browsers ?

Comment: Its compatible to most browsers.